# Spring boot MYSQL connection error with docker compose file

Tags: java, mysql, docker-compose

I get mysql connection refused error when I build my docker-compose file. The application exists the code but mysql keeps running.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAfW6.png)

## So I tried running it without the compose file and it worked perfectly. I was able to to post and fetch data. However, when I use the multi-stage dockerfile, I get connection issues

`application.properties`

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:${MYSQL_PORT:3306}/${MYSQL_DATABASE:xloan}

spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_USER:root}

spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD:root}

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

`Dockerfile`

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy as base

WORKDIR /app

COPY .mvn/ .mvn

COPY mvnw pom.xml ./

RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve

COPY src ./src

FROM base as development

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run", "-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=mysql", "-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments='-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000'"]

FROM base as build

RUN ./mvnw package

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy as production

EXPOSE 8080

COPY --from=build /app/target/microcreditApp-*.jar /microcreditApp.jar

CMD ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/microcreditApp

`My docker-compose.dev.yml`

version: '3.8'

services:

app:

```
build:

  context: .

  target: development

image: java-docker

ports:

  - "8000:8000"

  - "8080:8080"

environment:

  - SERVER_PORT=8080

  - SPRING.DATASOURCE.URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver:3306/xloan

  - SPRING.DATASOURCE.USERNAME=root

  - SPRING.DATASOURCE.PASSWORD=password

  - MYSQL_HOST=mysqlserver

  - MYSQL_USER=root

  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root

  - MYSQL_DATABASE=xloan

volumes:

  - ./:/app

depends_on:

  - mysqlserver
```

mysqlserver:

```
image: mysql:8.0

ports:

  - "3307:3306"

environment:

  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password

  - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true

  - MYSQL_USER=root

  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root

  - MYSQL_DATABASE=xloan

volumes:

  - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

  - mysql_config:/etc/mysql/conf.d
```

volumes:

mysql_data:

mysql_config:

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, where MySQL is refusing the connection, typically means that the application is unable to reach the MySQL server. This can happen for various reasons, and in your case, it might be related to the Docker Compose setup and environment variables.

Here are some steps you can take to diagnose and potentially resolve the issue:

1. Ensure Docker Compose is Using the Correct Compose File:

   - Double-check that you are using the correct Docker Compose file when running your application. It looks like you are using `docker-compose.dev.yml`, which is the development version. Make sure this is the intended behavior.
2. Correct Environment Variable Names:

   - In your `docker-compose.dev.yml`, you are defining environment variables with uppercase names (e.g., `SPRING.DATASOURCE.URL`). However, in your `application.properties`, you are using lowercase names (e.g., `spring.datasource.url`). Ensure that the environment variable names in your `docker-compose.dev.yml` match the property names in your Spring Boot application.
3. Verify Network Connectivity:

   - Ensure that your application container can reach the MySQL container. You are using a custom network by default when using Docker Compose, so it should be accessible by service name. In your Spring Boot configuration, you're using `MYSQL_HOST=mysqlserver`, which should resolve to the MySQL service container. Verify that the service name is correct and reachable from your Spring Boot container.
4. Check Port Mappings:

   - You have defined port mappings in your Docker Compose file. Make sure that the ports are correctly mapped, and there are no conflicts with other services or containers running on your host machine.
5. Check the MySQL Container:

   - Ensure that your MySQL container is running and has initialized correctly. You can check the MySQL container logs for any errors or issues.
6. Use Docker Compose Overrides (optional):

   - If you want to customize environment variables for your development environment, consider using a `.env` file or Docker Compose environment overrides. This way, you can maintain a consistent configuration across different environments.

To further diagnose the issue, you can check the logs of both the Spring Boot application and the MySQL container for any specific error messages. This can help pinpoint the cause of the connection issue.

Additionally, you can try running the Spring Boot application and MySQL containers individually with Docker Compose to see if they work in isolation. This can help determine if the issue is related to the interaction between the two services or if it's specific to one of them.

If you are still facing issues after checking these points, please provide any specific error messages or logs you receive during the connection refusal, which can help with further diagnosis.

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2023-10-21 21:59:16     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2023-10-21 21:59:16     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
2023-10-21 21:59:16     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:547) ~[na:na]
2023-10-21 21:59:16     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602) ~[na:na]
2023-10-21 21:59:16     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]]